# Toggle all elements except the sub element of clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to toggle(show/hide) the `<p>` which is the sub-element of the clicked `<li>`, while all other `<p>`s should should hide. I was able to do this.

**But clicking on the same element(which is now showing) does not hide.** How to achieve this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("li").click(function(){
        $("p").not(this).hide(200);
        $("p", this).toggle(200);
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a>q1</a>
    <p>a1</p>
  </li>
  <li><a>q2</a>
    <p>a3</p>
  </li>
  <li><a>q3</a>
    <p>a3</p>
  </li>
  <li><a>q4</a>
    <p>a4</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/pz89huqL/ kindly check this out

Comment: @guradio Its not hiding other tags

Comment: @Munawir what do you mean not hiding?kindly check again

Comment: Refer this [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/pz89huqL/1/)

Comment: @NidhinPrathap works fine. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `p` elements to be excluded to `not()`, you are now passing `this` which is referring to the `li` element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("p").hide();
  $("li").click(function() {
    var $ps = $("p", this).stop(true).toggle(200);
    $("p").not($ps).stop(true).hide(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a>q1</a>
      <p>a1</p>
    </li>
    <li><a>q2</a>
      <p>a3</p>
    </li>
    <li><a>q3</a>
      <p>a3</p>
    </li>
    <li><a>q4</a>
      <p>a4</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("li").click(function(){
        $(this).find('p').toggle(200);
        $(this).siblings('p').hide(200);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/pz89huqL/)
Try doing like this

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple logic :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("li").click(function(){

        $("p").not(this).hide(200);

       if($("p",this).is(":visible")){
        $("p", this).hide(200);}
       else{
       $("p", this).show(200);}
    });
});
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/e5oe0v09/) fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Change your jQuery code like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("li").click(function(){
        $("p").not($(this).find("p")).hide(200);
        $(this).find("p").toggle(200);
    });
});
```